# javascript - Can't catch outer function in nested function

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5

I write a custom function for aJax which named myCsrfAjax.

```
function myCsrfAjax(method, url, callback, jsonData) {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ...
    ...
}
```

It work fine. But in this case , I put it in some nested function , just like ,

```
var app = require('express');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    console.log("New Connection: " + socket.id);

    socket.on("disconnect", function () {
        console.log("disconnect:" + socket.id);
        myCsrfAjax("POST","/msgboard/removeid",function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },{"id":sockst.id});
        // ** ← even I defined 'function myCsrfAjax' here
    });
});
```

and error happen , it say "myCsrfAjax" is undefined , even I defined 'function myCsrfAjax' at ** , it will say "XMLHttpRequest" is undefined which I need to use it in myCsrfAjax. How can I fix this problem , please help me.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is not defined in nodejs enviroment

Comment: ok , I got it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myCsrfAjax = function(method, url, callback, jsonData) {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ...
    ...
}
```

Assign it to a `var` outside the `io.on()` scope, like after this line:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```